# Как сделать, чтобы приложение работало в Kiosk mode?

Tags: android

Есть ли такой режим работы android приложения как kiosk mode? Как его активизирвать?

Answer (score 3):

Начиная с Android 5, есть [такая](https://4idroid.com/izuchaem-android-5-0-blokirovka-v-prilozhenii/) функция "Блокировка в приложении".

То есть если устройство планируется использовать в какой либо стойке, то необходимо запустить приложение в данном режиме и скрыть физически кнопки(меню, назад), что бы нельзя было выйти из данного режима.
 Статус бар при этом становится недоступным.

Comment: спасибо, за инфо - век живи, век учись - буду знать!

Comment: @Barmaley в таком случае и вас благодарю, много чего полезного из ваших ответов почерпнул ;)

Answer (score 1):

Если кратко: это невозможно. Есть некоторые способы хакинга, как добиться скрытия некоторых функций оси, которые доступны конечному юзеру - более-менее это [описано здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/149561/)

Answer (score 1):

Режим киоска и на Windows не применяют на стандартных компьютерах, а на специально сконструированных, таких, как банкоматы, терминалы - с корпусами без кнопки Reset, открытых разъемов и прочего. А если такое же делать для Android, то можно просто закрыть от пользователя все аппаратные кнопки поместив устройство в специальный корпус, саму Activity сделать полноэкранной (чтобы Status bar не дергали). Если же будут доступны аппаратные кнопки, а именно кнопка питания, то вообще не вполне уверен, что можно полностью ее деактивировать, даже внеся изменения в ОС.

Answer (score 0):

Я для себя нашел ответы тут:
http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/
, хотя полностью добиться данного режима не получилось. Приходится блокировать кнопки физически, специальным чехлом